# I'm trying to create a linked service(rest) within azure synapse but I dont have authorization

Tags: azure, azure-synapse, azure-rest-api

I'm trying to create New linked service (REST) using copy data to copy data from an API to blob storage in a synapse workspace. When I try to create the new linked service (REST) I get the error down below. In the synapse workspace my level of acces is owner (my type is user) so I don't understand why I can't create the linked service. Where and what should my access level be changed in to give me access to create the linked service?

> Failed to save greenyapi. Error: Customers subscription: 2bc766cd-8609-428b-aa51-ed6643804cb3 is not in Registered state and cannot create or update resources. Current State: Suspended.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is resolved. It was a problem with the free trail, it needed to be renewed after a month so some functions could not be used.